# Automatically switch back to NerdTree after pressing "o" on file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I press "o" on any file in NerdTree list, it opens this file in one of currently opened tabs. Sometimes, when I'm not 100% sure what file to open, I have to do this:

1) o (open file)

2) ctrl-ww (switch back to nerdtree)

3) j or k (go to next file)
repeat 1-3 many times

I want to be able to press Alt-o to open file and switch back to NerdTree.
I tried this:

```
map <M-o> o<C-w>w

map <M-o> oC-ww
```

and both didn't work. What is wrong and how can I fix my mapping?

Comment: You didn't [RTFM](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L223), did you?

Comment: @romainl, Thank you for pointing at this; unfortunately I missed this command when I took a look at the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built into the plugin; the `go` command does this:

> go    Open selected file, but leave cursor in the NERDTree